# Evaluation of a Ruby variable in a jQuery statement passed to :onclick in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm iterating over records and want to create the toggle-options for records but I can't replace the div-id with the records:

```
<% for bill in @bills %>
<% tmp = "test"%>
<%= link_to '&raquo now','#', :onclick => '$("#{tmp}").toggle();' %>
```

Instead of getting:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(&quot;#test&quot;);">&raquo now</a>
```

I'm getting:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(&quot;#{tmp}&quot;).toggle();">&raquo now</a>
```

So there isn't evaluation of the ruby variable in the string. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help and I'm new in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for string interpolation to work in Ruby the string needs to be enclosed in **double quotes** i.e. rather than:

```
:onclick => '$("#{tmp}").toggle();'
```

use one of the following alternatives:

- surround the string in double quotes and escape the literal double quotes that occur in the string:

  `onclick => "$(\"#{tmp}\").toggle();`
- use the `%Q` notation then you won't need to escape the double quotes:

  `:onclick => %Q{$("#{tmp}").toggle();}`
- use double quotes in the Ruby code and single quotes in the JavaScript that will be generated:

  `:onclick => "$('#{tmp}'.toggle();"`

Comment: Hi mikej,

the solution was finally: :onclick => "$(\"\##{tmp}\").toggle();"

I needed to include the # for the id.